# vmstat: What are non-nice user cpu ticks?

Tags: linux

Anyone know what the "**non-nice user cpu ticks**" line in vmstat -s means?

For example:

```
# vmstat -s
   127180  total memory
    23436  used memory
     9828  active memory
     6744  inactive memory
   103744  free memory
        0  buffer memory
     9172  swap cache
        0  total swap
        0  used swap
        0  free swap
     1572 non-nice user cpu ticks
        0 nice user cpu ticks
     2632 system cpu ticks
     8543 idle cpu ticks
        0 IO-wait cpu ticks
       21 IRQ cpu ticks
        5 softirq cpu ticks
        0 stolen cpu ticks
        0 pages paged in
        0 pages paged out
        0 pages swapped in
        0 pages swapped out
    47872 interrupts
    53183 CPU context switches
   1331129846 boot time
         1010 forks
```

Answer (score 2):

any cpu tick by user process which was not nice'd 
nice is a way to change priorities of processes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)
if you do not use this command to manipulate priorities you most likely end up all your user cpu ticks in  the non nice section of the stats